# Regex: Match repeating digits ignoring of non-digits

Tags: .net, regex, phone-number

I have a list of messy phone numbers and some (likely fake) contain the same repeating digit throughout, but may also contain other punctuation, spaces, letters, etc. How can I identify such numbers with .NET RegEx. Here is an example:

```
00000000000000
(11)1111111111
22/ 222-2222222222
cell +33,333-3333-3333.
14 244-44444 Ext. 444
```

I need regex to match first 4, but not the last one which has other digits. My `^(\d)\1+$` catches the first number. I also tried `^([.-[\D]])\1+$` to match a repeating character that is not a non-digit. Failed. Same for `^(\d)(?:[\1-[\D]])+$`. A simple way would be to remove all non-digits in one pass with `\D` and then use the first regex, but I don't want to create 2 calls to a regex engine (these are expensive CLR calls from within SQL Server).

The output is a simple boolean 0-1 for each line. 0 when there is no match and 1 when there is a match:

```
1
1
1
1
0
```

UPDATE:
To extend this question a bit. What would be a replacement regex if I want to erase the whole line, whenever regex has a match? So, the replacement regex would return 4 blank lines and one original line. I'm trying to do this with a lookaround, but failing.

Comment: can you show us what your output should look like? that way it is easy to see what needs to be done

Comment: This is a match/no match output. So, 1 if a line has a matching string and 0 if it does not.

Comment: Try [`^\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jYSfW1/2)

Comment: Seems to work. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)+\D*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jYSfW1/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `(\d)` - Group 1: a digit
- `(?:\D*\1)+` - 1 or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
  - `\1` - the same digit as captured in Group 1
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. It also seems to work with my replacement regex :)